# How to start and stop Timer in Android?

Tags: android, timer

Please any one tell me how to start the Timer and How to stop that

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) you find all the necessary information. As you can see there are various methods to start your timer. Just use the appropriate `schedule(...)` method. In order to stop the timer you can use the cancel() method and afterwards the purge() method. But be aware that the cancel() method cancels all tasks that are associated with this timer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the `Timer` class?

You can use the `schedule` methods to schedule a `TimerTask` and `TimerTask#cancel` to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the countdown timer..

Timer.cancel();

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this Working Code.
    package com.example.stopwatch;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.SystemClock;
   import android.util.Log;

   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.Chronometer;
   import android.widget.CompoundButton;

    import android.widget.ToggleButton;

    public class StopWatch extends Activity {
    Chronometer mChronometer;

    Button button;
    private long start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    private long stop = 0;
    private long totalPauseTime = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            try {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.main);


                final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton)           findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
                final Chronometer chrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

                final ToggleButton toggle2 = (ToggleButton)        findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
                final Chronometer chrono2 = (Chronometer)           findViewById(R.id.chronometer2);

      toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                try {
                    Log.i("[chrono]", String.format("start:%d stop:%d delta: %d",start, stop, start - stop));
                    Log.i("[chrono]", "base:" +chrono.getBase());
                    Log.i("[chrono]", "elapsed time:" +SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                    if (isChecked) {
                        chrono.start();
                        start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                        chrono.setBase(start - totalPauseTime);
                    } else {
                        totalPauseTime +=    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start;
                        chrono.stop();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

  }
   });

     toggle2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                      boolean isChecked) {
                 try {
                    Log.i("[chrono]", String.format("start:%d    stop:%d         delta: %d",start, stop, start - stop));
                    Log.i("[chrono]", "base:" +chrono.getBase());
                    Log.i("[chrono]", "elapsed time:"   +SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                      if (isChecked) {
                          chrono2.start();
                          start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                          chrono2.setBase(start - totalPauseTime);
                    } else {
                        totalPauseTime +=                 SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start;
                        chrono2.stop();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {


    enter code here

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }
    });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }       }
```